# How to load data into target tables when column value equal to either Insert, Update, Delete or None

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have two target tables one is target table and the other one is error table. We have Firm and Indiv source tables to be loaded into target table and error table. I am using union to pass Indiv and Firm data into the target table and error table separately which is straight move.
Now, I need to check if Firm.Action= Insert and if record already exists in target table then we are passing record to error table, if firm.action=update and present in target table we are updating else passing to error table. We also have firm.action=delete and firm.action=None then records can be ignored.

Comment: Have you tried to do this at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can check presence of record int table using lookup transformation, after that in expression transformation you can evaluate your conditions.

For example,

```
IIF(Firm.Action= 'Insert' and is_record_in_lookup = 1, 'Error', ... )
```